# Capitalize the HTML <option> selected Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to Capitalize the HTML  selected Attribute, but does not work !

```
<option value="${city}" style="text-transform: capitalize"> ${fn:toLowerCase(city)}</option>
```

Comment: It can depend on the other/parent styles that you have in the project, try to add !important property to the style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments on the answer suggesting the CSS `text-transform` method, there seems to be an inconsistency with Chrome. Scouring the web, this seems to be, at some point - a known issue. See [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-bugs/tUAG96K1_ls) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31349) for some details. Unsure how long this has been known, perhaps even resolved at some point, but per Chrome version 43.0.2357.124 m on Windows, I can still [replicate this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/fdybv7dx/) - see [screen cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TClte.png) as well

If Chrome consistency is substantial enough of an issue, you may be able to work around this with some JavaScript. Some examples may include...

jQuery - [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1pvt3d6b/)

```
$('option').each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function($1){ return $1.toUpperCase(); }));
});
```

---

Vanilla - [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u442Lkha/)

```
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('OPTION')

for(var i = 0; i < ele.length; i += 1) {
    ele[i].text = ele[i].text.replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function($1){ return $1.toUpperCase(); })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set it on the `<select>` element.

```html
<select style="text-transform: capitalize">
    <option value="volvo">volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">saab</option>
    <option value="opel">opel</option>
    <option value="audi">audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in latest Chrome, only the first option is being capitalized

Comment: Are you sure? because it's working all fine here Chrome 43.0.2357.124.

Comment: My bad about first option being capitalized, slight confusion there. It seems that all are still lower cased. See [this cap](http://i.imgur.com/hlfLPfE.png). Chrome version 43.0.2357.124 m

Comment: Very interesting, I'm on the Mac and don't have a Windows to test at the moment, let's see if anyone also reporting the same thing. By the way it looks all fine here on Firefox too.

Comment: I am also using Chrome Version 43.0.2357.124 m, the selected option gets it first letter capitalised: all options in the drop down menu are completely lower case.

Comment: I managed to test it out on Chrome 42.0.2311.152 Windows, all looks capitalized, it very much sounds like a bug to me on v43.x. Also tested on IE11 and Firefox 38 all good too.

Comment: Strange. I see this is a know issue, but some answers on SO claimed this was resolved at some point. Unsure how long this has been problematic. I posted a JS solution if the OP is turned off enough with Chrome support at time of writing, though the css solution would be ideal @sdcr

Comment: @jaunt see my JS suggestion since you experienced the same